# Mouse is inverted in Unity when I click play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I followed a tutorial on youtube to learn how to look around:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJqP5EesxLk (16:55 is the start of looking)

and when I go in, down is up, and vice versa.

My code is below:

(INPUT MANAGER)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private PlayerInput playerInput;
private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

private PlayerMotor motor; 
private PlayerLook look; 
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    playerInput = new PlayerInput();
    onFoot = playerInput.OnFoot;

    motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    look = GetComponent<PlayerLook>();

    onFoot.Jump.performed += ctx => motor.Jump();
}
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // tell the player to move using the value from our movement action.
    motor.ProcessMove(onFoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    look.ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
}
private void OnEnable()
{
    onFoot.Enable();
}
private void OnDisable()
{
onFoot.Disable();
}
}
```

(PLAYER LOOK)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour
{
public Camera cam;
private float xRotation = 0f;

public float xSensitivity = 30f;
public float ySensetivity = 30f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
public void ProcessLook(Vector2 input)
{
    float mouseX = input.x;
    float mouseY = input.y;
    //calculate camera rotation for looking up and down
    xRotation += (mouseY * Time.deltaTime) * ySensetivity;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80f, 80f);
    //apply this to our camera to transform
    cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
    //rotate player to look left and right
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * (mouseX * Time.deltaTime) * xSensitivity);
}
}
```

If someone could give me a fix and tell me what I did wrong, I would be grateful.

I've tried changing the float sensetivities, & xRotation, neither worked.

Comment: So, I've figured out that it is following my cursor, I don't know how to make it look up with up instead of  down with up as if im holding right click and scrolling

Comment: simply invert the direction (`* -1`) ..?

Answer (score 0):

try this to invert the X axis

```
float mouseX = (input.x * -1);
```

and this to invert the Y axis

```
float mouseY = (input.y * -1);
```